# Create customized bookmark in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, bookmarks

Let's say, I have a URL of the form

http://mySite.com/?param=123

Now the page shows diff content based on the "param" value..

So can I create a bookmark in IE such that as soon as I click it in the Favorites bar, it will prompt to enter this value (e.g 123) and then directly append it to the URL and take me to that page..

Comment: I *don't think so*. You could edit the URI in the browsers address bar, but most users pay very little attention to what's in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a bookmarklet.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

Answer (score 0):

If `http://mySite.com/` (no parameters) has that prompt in it, then you could simply bookmark that URL.